# Yii2, Dompdf - pdf doesn't render anything

Tags: php, yii, yii2, dompdf

I am having a bit of an issue with **Dompdf**. It is refusing to render anything, and PDF document is white blank. This is the code I have so far:

```
class PDFHelper

    {
        static public function purchase($data)
        {
            $dompdf = new Dompdf();
            $dompdf->loadHtml('<p>Test</p>');

            return $dompdf->stream('PDF Document');
        }

    }
```

Quite basic, but it is refusing to do anything. I have installed Dompdf via composer: **"dompdf/dompdf": "dev-master"**
What is going wrong here?

Comment: the extension you are using isnt maintained anymore as the link to the gihub is giving `404` try using [MPDF](http://demos.krajee.com/mpdf) by kartik intead

Answer (score 0):

Use **wkhtmltopdf** instead.

Php-based converters as far as I know are very unstable.